# sklearn Dictionarylearning - how to validate dictionary?

Tags: scikit-learn

I'm using sklearn DictionaryLearning to detect anomaly in time series data.

My question is: how can I estimate which is the write size for the Dictionary, i.e. number of atoms to use? Could anyone help to find useful examples, available reading?

I'd assume atoms should be as linearly independent as possible and no repetitions among atoms. But, how can I check this?

Comment: The only way you can get answer to your question is through trial and error and Cross Validation

Comment: Thanks! But, how about distance or similarity measures between atoms? For example cosine similarity or euclidean distance between atoms, would that give any insights?